# Eclipse luna duplicate method names

Tags: java, eclipse, eclipse-luna

**Background:** The main issue we've been encountering is our Eclipse Helios running in Redhat linux Santiago 6 crashes and sometimes not responding. We are not able to figure out the root cause and tried different solutions i've read from different sites including stackoverflow.

**What i have done so far:** So i have decided to download Eclipse Luna and imported the existing projects from my Eclipse Helios and changed the installed jre in eclipse luna to jrockit built in WLS 1.8(as we are using a legacy framework)

**Issue:** After i imported my existing project, there's a problem with eclipse luna.

```
Duplicate methods named put with the parameters (K, V) and (Object, Object) are inherited from the types HashMap and AbstractMap

The method put(Object, Object) is ambiguous for the type
```

But this error is not being encountered in eclipse helios.

I also download eclipse Juno, Kepler but same issue as luna.

**Question:** Is there a workaround for this or how can i turn off and ignore this error in eclipse luna?

**Edit: Sample Code As requested**

This is one of the classes that has error.

```
public class DummyMessageMap extends HashMap implements MessageMap {
  // implementation of the interface but returns null values.
}

public interface MessageMap extends Map{

    public Message getMessage(String key);
    public String getLanguage();
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The problem here is that the interface `java.util.Map` reaches your class `DummyMessageMap` via two paths, i.e., `DummyMessageMap extends HashMap extends AbstractMap implements Map` and `DummyMessageMap implements MessageMap extends Map`. In the second path, as the error shows, the generic types `K` and `V` got specified as `object` and `object` in your code. This is a design smell called `Multipath Hierarchy` and there is no way but to get rid of this path conflict. Try removing `extends Map` from `MessageMap` if possible.

Comment: But how come this error is not being encountered in Eclipse Helios? How can i ignore this error?

Comment: I don't know why Eclipse Helios doesn't show this but this **is** an error in any platform. I have no idea in `ignoring errors` but I strongly recommend you to fix this but. Ignoring is not a good option.

Comment: One way you could get rid of the error is to find where did the generics `K` and `V` got specified as `Object` and `Object`. If you either remove the specification in the second path or make the specification in the first path, the signature of the function from both the paths will be same at last and the error will not occur.

Answer (score 0):

This seems like a overloading issue to me.

Java can not determine which one to use if the parameters are the same. So, it throws a duplicate method error instead.

Try to change the method parameters and test your program again, chances are your error is coming from overloading a method incorrectly.

Comment: I'm not sure about that. `HashMap` extends `AbstractMap`, I can't see how this error would crop up from incorrect overloading.

Comment: And also why am i not experiencing this issue in eclipse helios?

Comment: I can't simply change the code as it affects lot of classes and just for the sake of compatibility for eclipse as this might introduce bugs and other issues on the code.